# How to select multiple dom elements in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

```
<div class="modalmenu"  >
  <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin(sepinout)" (mouseleave)="sepout(sepinout)"><a href="#in">HOME</a></div>
  <div class="sep" #sepinout></div>
  <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin(sepinout)" (mouseleave)="sepout(sepinout)"><a href="#ab">SOBRE MI</a></div>
  <div class="sep" #sepinout></div>
  <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin(sepinout)" (mouseleave)="sepout(sepinout)"><a href="#his">HISTORIA</a></div>
  <div class="sep" #sepinout></div>
  <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin(sepinout)" (mouseleave)="sepout(sepinout)"><a href="#ex">EXPERIENCIA</a></div>
  <div class="sep" #sepinout></div>
  <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin(sepinout)" (mouseleave)="sepout(sepinout)"><a href="#cont">CONTACTO</a></div>
  <div class="sep" #sepinout></div>
</div>
```

```
export class NavBarComponent {
  sepin(sepinout: HTMLElement){
    sepinout.style.translate = "0px"
  }

  sepout(sepinout: HTMLElement){
    sepinout.style.translate = "-2000px"
  }
}
```

The selector tag #sepinout only selects one element, I don't know how to select several at the same time, and that this function is fulfilled for all the elements of the list

I tried to use the same selector but it doesn't seem to work as the action happens with only one element

**UPDATE / SOLUTION**

```
<div class="modalmenu">
      <span class="material-symbols-outlined nbcont_x">close</span>
      <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin(sepinout)" (mouseleave)="sepout(sepinout)"><a href="#in">HOME</a></div>
      <div class="sep" #sepinout></div>
      <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin(sepinout1)" (mouseleave)="sepout(sepinout1)"><a href="#ab">SOBRE MI</a></div>
      <div class="sep" #sepinout1></div>
      <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin(sepinout2)" (mouseleave)="sepout(sepinout2)"><a href="#his">HISTORIA</a></div>
      <div class="sep" #sepinout2></div>
      <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin(sepinout3)" (mouseleave)="sepout(sepinout3)"><a href="#ex">EXPERIENCIA</a></div>
      <div class="sep" #sepinout3></div>
      <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin(sepinout4)" (mouseleave)="sepout(sepinout4)"><a href="#cont">CONTACTO</a></div>
      <div class="sep" #sepinout4></div>
</div>

export class NavBarComponent {
  sepin(sepinout: HTMLElement){
    sepinout.style.translate = "0px"
  }

  sepout(sepinout: HTMLElement){
    sepinout.style.translate = "-2000px"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ViewChildren to get all the elements of your html

```html
<div class="modalmenu">
  <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin()" (mouseleave)="sepout()"><a href="#in">HOME</a></div>
  <div class="sep" #sepinout></div>
  <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin()" (mouseleave)="sepout()"><a href="#ab">SOBRE MI</a></div>
  <div class="sep" #sepinout></div>
  <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin()" (mouseleave)="sepout()"><a href="#his">HISTORIA</a></div>
  <div class="sep" #sepinout></div>
  <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin()" (mouseleave)="sepout()"><a href="#ex">EXPERIENCIA</a></div>
  <div class="sep" #sepinout></div>
  <div class="modal_itm" (mouseenter)="sepin()" (mouseleave)="sepout()"><a href="#cont">CONTACTO</a></div>
  <div class="sep" #sepinout></div>
</div>
```

**TypeScript**

```js
  @ViewChildren('sepinout') sepinouts!: QueryList<any>;

  sepout() {
    this.translateElements('0');
  }

  sepin() {
    this.translateElements('-2000px');
  }

  translateElements(translate: string) {
    this.sepinouts.toArray().forEach((item: any) => {
      item.nativeElement.style.translate = translate;
    });
  }
```

I hope it helps you